# How to submit data entered in the forms directly into database?

Tags: python, django

I have designed a form in django wherein there are 3 fields "Title","Body" & "Tagline". So my query is that when i press submit button after filling up the data that data should be directly inserted into my "notes" database.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class pim(models.Model):

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Body = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    TagLine = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def Notes_create(request):
    return render_to_response('notesform.html',locals())
```

Comment: The main concern is actually what code needs to be written inorder to make it work..

Plz do tell us about your thought on how to make this work...
thanks

Comment: Please read the documentation on [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/) and [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/), then come back if you have any **specific** questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a modelform for your pim model:

```
class pimForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pim
```

And your view will have to display the form and handle it when the request type is a POST:

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = pimForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('your.pim.detail.view', args=[pim.pk]))
    else:
        form = pimForm()
    return render_to_response('notesform.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Something like that should work